# iframe vk autoplay

Tags: vkontakte-api, iframe

Есть ли параметр автовоспроизведения в iframe видео вконтакте? Гуглил - не нашел

Answer (score 2):

Для ВКонтакте работает `autoplay=1`, аналогично YouTube.
[Пример](https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-118278117&id=456239025&hash=7d65580ee6e1c306&hd=2&autoplay=1)